# Busybox /init: line 49: can't open /dev/sr0: no medium found

Tags: boot

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 in a Live environment and I haven't had any problems up until this morning when I get this message. I don't have anything I need saved so I would love to just format the USB and start over but it also tells me it's write protected Gparted won't work on the drive either.

I could use help getting it reformatted to start over or help fixing this error

Comment: You don't need to 'format' the thumb-drive, just re-write the ISO to it.  While it's in use it'll be protected (the image is also written as a write-protected image to prevent corruption, but that won't stop you just overwriting the thumb-drive in the same manner on which it was first written).  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: I used Rufus to make it, and when I try using it again Rufus tells me it's Write-protected. Is there any other way to try re-writing the ISO to it?

Comment: I have never used `rufus` so can't help there, but the only time i've experience write-protected thumb-drives was because they were in a RO state (ie. physical switch on the drive itself set to RO; and few thumb-drives contain this functionality on them so this is unlikely). Excluding hardware lock (thumb-drive RO mode) I've always just `dd` the data to the thumb-drive & it whatever was on it overwritten (unless media itself was/is faulty; you could test it).  But note I've never used `rufus`